# Profile Menubar Tab Opens Automatically

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

When viewing the [Ask Different blog](http://apple.blogoverflow.com) when logged in, the Dashboard/Navigation bar is visible. On page load, the profile tab (the tab with your name on it) opens until you move your mouse. It's a bit distracting, and I'm fairly certain it's not supposed to happen.

I recorded a quick video demonstrating the issue:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJoxt7M41SA

Upon further examination, it appears to be happening on the main page, and a single blog post page. It does *not* happen on "pages" (like, [for podcast guests](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/for-podcast-guests/)), nor the archive/about page.

Comment: I can reproduce this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed by a WordPress update in the meantime.